# what is the best way to manipulate the following string?

Tags: java, string

I have strings like:

```
"{0}_something_{1}-{2}-something"
```

and i need to convert these strings to

```
"%s_something_%s-%s-something"
```

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What's the logic here? When to add an underscore?

Comment: no logic in underscores. only replacing all the {0}, {1} with %s. I forgot the string.replce is with regex. i got my answer down here. thanks

Comment: then replace your example with "How should I replace all instances of `{0]...{1}...` and etc. with `%s`.

Comment: Where do you want to place `_`?

Comment: @Kaj. as i said - there is no logic  for the underscores.  sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a regexp.

```
String data = "{0}something{1}-{2}-something";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}", "%s_"));
```

Output:

`%s_something%s_-%s_-something`

Edit:
A regexp that only replaces if there only are digits between `{` and `}`

```
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("\\{\\d+\\}", "%s_"));
```

Comment: @dan: Careful, this solution will leave `-` in place. Furthermore, it will not match only digits between the braces, but any character. Take a look at my answer for a complete tested solution.

Comment: @Shef. The example that dan posted does still have `-` in the output. That's why I'm not trying to remove it. Did however post a new regexp that only matches if there are digits between `{}`

Comment: Yes, that will match only digits. Okay, if he still wants the `-`, that's what he wants. ;) Good job.

Answer (score 6):

```
myString.replaceAll("\\{\\d\\}", "%s")
```

If you're trying to create a Java format string, then you should *probably* retain the order of those replacements, otherwise strings like  `foo {2} bar {1} baz {0}` will pose problems:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\{(\\d)\\}", "%$1$$s");
```

Comment: That regexp isn't replacing what he wants to replace

Comment: Huh? He says that he wants this output `%s_something_%s-%s-something` my regexp is producing that output.

Comment: thanks. but you need "\\" before the "{". otherwise you get PatternSyntaxException: illegal repetition.

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry. I'm not quite aure about the second one, either. Could be that Java uses `\` instead of `$` to escape backreferences from the match in the replacement part.

Comment: @Joey, just saw that the sample output by the OP isn't consistent on where to place '_'

Comment: Kaj: It was just a formatting issue. Looking into the question source often helps clarifying things.

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = MessageFormat.format("{0}something{1}-{2}-something", "%s_", "_%s", "%s");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str      =   "{0}something{1}-{2}-something";
String clean    =   str.replaceAll("(\\{\\d+\\}-?)", "%s_");
System.out.println(clean); // outputs: %s_something%s_%s_something
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MessageFormat. - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html